# Custom event triggering performances (jQuery / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Are there performance issues depending on which elements triggers a jQuery event?

```
 $('body').on('myEvent',function(e){
    // access to e properties
 });


 $('#innerDiv').on('myEvent',function(e){
   // access to e properties
 });
```

Which one is better?
In the first case "e" carries more information than "e" returned in the second snippet.

So the "e" returned in the first case is a bigger object than the "e" returned in the second case. The question is, does this affects JavaScript performances? Heap? Memory? Or this object "e", independently from his size is already cached and easy-accessible?

Is it a good practice make "lighter objects" triggering events instead the entire body, document or html?

Comment: as ID must be unique on context page, the second one would be the best option here

Answer (score 1):

`Event Delegation` will be the better option

```
$('body').on('myEvent', '#innerDiv' ,function(e){
     // access to e properties
});
```